Order of decarboxylation of compounds
Checking the carbanion stability, I get that (c) > (d) because NO₂ is a better -M group than -CN and the +I effect in (c) & (d) does not affect much as is weaker than -M. However in the first two, how to compare -I and +I effects.
The correct order given in the book is (c)>(d)>(b)>(a)

